# Looking for Ruby code on Metasploit commands

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

Can anyone tell me where in a normal Kali Linux install I can find the Ruby code for the Meterpreter commands cat and edit?

I've been looking in `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/post/windows` and `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/scripts` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meterpreter file system commands `cat` and `edit` are implemented in [`/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/stdapi/fs.rb`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/stdapi/fs.rb) by [`cmd_cat`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/stdapi/fs.rb#L153) and [`cmd_edit`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/stdapi/fs.rb#L312).